# How to invite someone for biking (The most common way)

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one of the following sentences sound more natural when you want to invite someone or a group of people to ride bicycles together:

> - Let’s go cycling.
> - Let’s go biking.
> - Let’s go ride bicycles.
> - Let’s go ride bikes.

Based on my dictionaries, they all work for me, but I cannot understand if there is a regional preference in the AE or not.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand them, there are some connotations that you might not know as a learner. I have provided pictures of what they **could** mean, without further context.

1. *Cycling*.
   [image]
2. *Biking*.
   [image]
   (*Short for mountain biking*.) I think there is also the possibility of understanding *biking* to mean riding motorcycles, the Harley-Davidson types.
3. *Ride bicycles*.
   [image]
   This is what I personally imagine: casual, roadside riding.
4. *Ride bikes*. Often means 3, but can also mean motorcycle riding.
   [image]
   (Motorcycles are sometimes called *bikes*.)

Now 1-4 are what I imagine without context. I suspect you mean something along the lines of 3. So if your audience expects bike-riding, like in 3, then I believe using "Let’s go biking/ride bicycles/ride bikes." should all work fine.

I think I would personally say "Let's go bike-riding." Again, it could mean *motorcycle*, but if your audience expects something like 3, then it should work fine. *Bicycle-riding* works too.